# Is it ok to Quick Nav selectively, not universally?

Tags: navigation, consistency, wayfinding

First, to keep us on the same page this is what I mean when I am saying **Quick Nav**. (Example from Lonely Planet) It is supplementary navigation to inform you what is on the page and send you down to the target content with anchor links.

[image]

While I am aware that generally, we want to ensure that we keep experiences consistent across pages; I am designing a site with the intention to keep most pages straight forward and to the point such that they wouldn't require a supplementary quick nav.

However, there are a couple of the overview pages I am considering using a quick nav style to enhance the usability.

So the root of my question is: **Is the added utility sufficient motivation to ignore the loss of consistency?**

My feeling is that it is ok, but I wanted to hear other's thoughts.

*(Again, I know without looking at the wireframes you don't have the proper context to judge this case specifically but am more so asking about the general convention.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I cannot say in more concise way, so it's just a quote and the recommendation to read the whole thing:

> **The problem with thinking in terms of consistency is that those thoughts focus purely on the design and the user can get lost.** “Is
>   what I’m designing consistent with other things we’ve designed (or
>   others have designed)?” is the wrong question to ask.
>
> Instead, the right question is, “Will the user’s current knowledge help them understand how to use what I’m designing?” Current knowledge
>   is the knowledge the user has when they approach the design. It’s the
>   sum of all their previous experiences with relevant products and
>   designs.

[Consistency in Design is the Wrong Approach](https://medium.com/@jmspool/consistency-in-design-is-the-wrong-approach-3cfbc87a327) by Jared Spool

Comment: This is sort of in line with what I had come to as well. I was focused on the wrong type of consistency. If quick nav is there or not doesn't effect consistency in the same way as having it presented in a way that visually is a drastic departure from the rest of the site for example. Thank you for your answer.